How to share SCSS variables across libs and apps in Nx project?
I have a React monorepo with 3 apps and many libraries. I want to create a dedicated library to hold my SASS variables and import this variables file into the SASS files of other libraries and apps within the monorepo.
What is the best way to set this up so that it works smoothly across development and production builds?
I'm working on an Nx project and have created a directory called shared-styles in the libs folder, which contains an SCSS variables.scss file.

In other libs and apps, I imported this file using:
@import "libs/shared-styles/variables";
This works fine in the development server. However, when building the project, I get the following error: cannot find the variables file.
I'm looking for a way to properly share SCSS variables across different libs and apps, so that it works during both development and production builds. How can I create a shared SCSS library that other libs and apps can import without build issues?
